# Using LocalDateTime with JAXB

Tags: java, time, jaxb

I am trying to use JAXB with fields of the `LocalDateTime` type. I wrote an adapter to handle conversion:

```
public class LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime arg0) throws Exception {
        return arg0.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String arg) throws Exception {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(arg);
    }
}
```

I registered the adapter in `package-info.java` like so:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDateTime.class, value=LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
})
package xml;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
```

This seems to be sufficient according to [this page](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and).
However, I keep getting the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.time.LocalDateTime does not have a no-arg default constructor.
```

I understand the reason for the exception being thrown, but I can hardly add a default constructor to `java.time.LocalDateTime`. This seems to be a shortcoming of the class / a strange design decision. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

What you have should work.  One of the following may be wrong:

1. Since you have specified the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` at the package level it will only apply to properties on classes in your package called `xml`.  Is there a class in your model from a different package that has a mapped property of type `LocalDateTime`?
2. It is also possible that your `package-info.java` file is not being compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Had same behaviour: `IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions`.

My pbm was: I have several packages (three) where the `package-info.java` file is needed, like shown in the [following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YEnc.png).

I "solved" this pbm by adding a `package-info.java` in each of the three directories. Example for package `fr.gouv.agriculture.dal.ct.planCharge.metier.dao.charge.xml`:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = LocalDate.class, value = LocalDateXmlAdapter.class)
package fr.gouv.agriculture.dal.ct.planCharge.metier.dao.charge.xml;
```

If someone has a better idea than copy/paste into several `package-info.java` files, thanks in advance.